# Change the name of Page N of M in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

​Hi,
I am creating a total quantity label statement in Crystal. I am using the Special Field Page N of M in my Details section

Is there a way to remove the text "Page" so that it will just display 1/2" in place instead of "Page 1/2"

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Special Field can't be modified, but you can create a formula to get the desired output:

```
CStr(PageNumber, "#") & "/" & CStr(TotalPageCount, "#")
```